# Pandas data frame method `to_gbq` handling nested data in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have read json data with nested objects into data frame using pandas `read_json`.

I would like to push that data into `Google Big Query` using pandas `to_gbq` but for nested elements getting error like these:

`StreamingInsertError: Error at Row: 0, Reason: invalid, Location: payment_details, Message: This field is not a record.`

where data frame looks like these:

```
df['payment_details'][1]
{u'credit_card_bin': u'xxxx', u'avs_result_code': u'Y', u'credit_card_company': u'Visa', u'cvv_result_code': u'M', u'credit_card_number': u'yyy'}
```

how one should it treat so that GBQ consumes it as record?

problems seems be somwhere here when mapping objects to strings
`pandas_gbq/gbq.py`

```
type_mapping = {
    'i': 'INTEGER',
    'b': 'BOOLEAN',
    'f': 'FLOAT',
    'O': 'STRING',
    'S': 'STRING',
    'U': 'STRING',
    'M': 'TIMESTAMP'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas_gbq` doesn't support structs or arrays, and it's not 'pandantic' to store dicts or lists in pandas `DataFrame`s

If you're using structs, can you use instead multiple columns in your `DataFrame`?